# How to infer type using generics?

Tags: swift, generics

I have defined some response models as

```
class UserProfile{

    var name:String = "Anish"
    var age:Int = 20
}

class StudentProfile:UserProfile{

    var std_id:Int = 1

}
```

I have a class for Web API request as

```
class WebCaller{

    class func callWebService<T>(responseType:T.Type,completionHandler:(T)->()){

        let model =  StudentProfile() as! responseType//wont compile here
        completionHandler(model)
    }
}
```

Which i want to call as

```
 WebCaller.callWebService(responseType: StudentProfile.self){ responseModel in
            //response model should automatically infer the type 
            print(responseModel.name)
            print(responseModel.age)
            print(responseModel.std_id)
        }
```

Now if i want to call as

```
 WebCaller.callWebService(responseType: UserProfile.self){ responseModel in
            //this should automaticaly infer the type
            print(responseModel.name)
            print(responseModel.age)
        }
```

However This can be accomplished using AnyObject type as

```
class func callWebService<T>(responseType:T.Type,completionHandler:(AnyObject)->())
```

But i need to cast it to my reponse type.What i am trying to acheieve is my API caller should send me the type so that i should not cast it in my `ViewModel`

Comment: Why don't this `let model =  StudentProfile() as! T` solves your problem?

Comment: Yes that does...But is that the way to go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

T.Type is almost unusable and you don't need any kind of generics to be used in your scenario

```
class A{
    let typeA = "property typeA"
}
class B{
    let typeB = "property typeB"
}
class C{}

func f0(object: AnyObject) {

        if let a = object as? A {
            print(1, a.typeA)
            return
        }

        if let b = object as? B {
            print(2, b.typeB)
            return
        }
        print("unknown type")
}

f0(object: A())
f0(object: B())

func f1(object: AnyObject) {
    switch object {
    case is A:
        let a = object as! A // will never fail!!
        print(3, a.typeA)
    case is B:
        let b = object as! B // will never fail!!
        print(4, b.typeB)
    default:
        print("unknown type")
        break
    }
}

f1(object: A())
f1(object: B())

f0(object: C())
f1(object: C())
```

it prints

```
1 property typeA
2 property typeB
3 property typeA
4 property typeB
unknown type
unknown type
```

to see what is the relationship between A and A.Type, compare what we have now to the next snippet, which gives you the same results

```
func f3(object: AnyObject) {
    switch type(of: object) {
    case is A.Type:
        let a = object as! A // will never fail!!
        print(5, a.typeA)
    case is B.Type:
        let b = object as! B // will never fail!!
        print(6, b.typeB)
    default:
        print("unknown type")
        break
    }
}
```

using the first scenario could be more practical, is there is some common functionality build in your objects.

```
protocol Printable {
}
extension Printable {
    func p(){
        print("I am printable", type(of: self))
    }
}
class A{
    let typeA = "property typeA"
}
class B: Printable{
    let typeB = "property typeB"
}
class C: Printable{}

func f0(object: AnyObject) {
    if let p = object as? Printable {
        p.p()
    }

    if let a = object as? A {
        print(1, a.typeA)
        return
    }

    if let b = object as? B {
        print(2, b.typeB)
        return
    }

    print("unknown type")
}

f0(object: A())
f0(object: B())
f0(object: C())
```

it prints

```
1 property typeA
I am printable B
2 property typeB
I am printable C
unknown type
```

Comment: sorry this contradicts the whole motive..I dont want to cast everytime...

Comment: @Costello so what do you want? Soon or later you need to cast the result to be able to use it, isn't it true?